# how to pass around double pointer in parameters so value is kept

Tags: c++, pointers, parameters

I have a void** p2 variable created like for example

```
int x = 10;
void* p = &x;
void** p2 = &p;
```

This is created in a function. How can I, using parameters or return value, pass this p2 in a way that p2 and * p2 both keep their exact value. I did not succeed in finding any solution. Please give me a short example, anything would do.

Maybe some details could help:

```
class ShmItem
{
public:
    void* start;
    void** vtable;
};
```

this class is global, its part of a global vector.
now in my function.

```
item.vtable = &item.start;
shm->address = item.vtable;
```

where item start holds the return value of mmap.

shm is an parameter object where address is of type void**.

Now when I return to the caller voila the value of `item.start` changes (in the `shm->address`)...

Sorry, I have found the bug, which has nothing to do with pointer. Can I delete this thread? Because the question makes no sense any more. (Although Carlos' way of passing double pointers across funcion calls is a good idea which helped me, so I marked it as answered).

Comment: Please tag your question with the desired language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using C right?
So, I think  you need to do two things.
First, declare you double pointer variable outside the function so it is in scope after the function returns.
Second, declare your function such that it receives and returns a void ** param that will hold the value you want, like so:

```
void **myfunc (void **p2) {
    int x = 10;
    void* p = &x;
    p2 = &p;  // notice var declaration is gone
    ...
    return p2;
}
void ** p2;
p2 = myfunc(p2);
```

You could also declare myfunc to return void and call myfunc with p2 without the assignment construct.

Comment: But if this works, would it also work if I pass an object which holds a void **p2 member, then I fill it out and read it out from the caller. I tried this, but it did not work. The * p value has been overwriten by concurrent variables.

Comment: actually I tried, if I make p and x global then using your method is a nice trick to avoid extra memory allocation (which would be very diffcult to free anyway). So I accept your method of passing around double pointers as a good idea!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot take the address of a local variable and return it from a function in any meaningful way, because the local variables will be out of scope by the time the function returns.

In the following code, both `x` and `p` are local to the function body:

```
void foo()
{
    int x = 10;
    void * p = &x;
}
```

The only sensible pointers you can pass around are those to objects which still exist by the time the function returns, i.e. either global objects, or dynamically allocated ones, or objects which were already passed *into* the function in the first place (e.g. by address in C, or by reference in C++).

Comment: Sorry, that was just an example, the variables are actually global

Comment: @user1132655: In that case it's completely unclear t me what your problem is. `&p` should be a valid expression everywhere in that case.

Comment: yes it is, and so p2 keeps its value but * p2 somehow dangles, any unrelatd memory alloc overwrites it.

Comment: I've put some details, maybe that could help.

Comment: Uhhhh, I've found the bug, it has nothing to do with pointers... Can I delete this whole thread, because the question is now of no value?

Comment: @user1132655: Yes, please do. There's a "delete" button at the bottom of your question, I believe. If that doesn't work, just flag it for moderator attention and say you want to delete the question because it's no longer relevant. Thanks!

Comment: Ah ok, sorry, I didnt see your answer.